# The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot read the data in Table

Tags: .net, oledb, ms-access-2013

I am writing a .Net application with back end database Access 2013
I connect using OLEDB connection and everything was working just fine

Then suddenly without doing any change to the code, database, Office versions, OLDEB, operating system, I started receiving the below exception when trying to execute select query against specific table

**Exception**

```
The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot read the data in MyTable.
The minimum required version to read the data is 14.0.0000.0000.
```

The interesting point, is that still I can execute same query against other tables with similar structure (but not identical) and almost same size of data

[I googled the exception](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/minimum-required-version-to-read-data-is/e5080f42-255b-4f4a-8206-e3884f4c6359?db=5&auth=1) and was excited to know it happened suddenly to other people as well
One of the suggested root causes, is the existence of calculated columns in my table, which is not the case

The below code takes table name as an argument, and works perfectly with all my tables except a specific table that has no big difference and was already working couple of hours ago.

```
 private void PupulateLookup(ComboBox control, string tableName, OleDbConnection conn)
    {
        BindingList<LookupObject> result = new BindingList<LookupObject>();

        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tableName);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

        OleDbDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
         //do my stuff
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
```

Exception is thrown on `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Do you have more than one Access versions? (if yes, make sure that your access file is set by default to open by your desired version).. moreover try to reinstall 'access database engine components' see if that might solve the problem

Comment: No, I have one version. I though to reinstall access database engine components, but as per my below answer the copy table trick fixed it, but I am still afraid it happens again and again

Comment: I updated my answer, as "copy table" solution dropped the relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with an illogical solution

1. I created new database
2. Imported all my tables from the old database to the new one

And unexpectedly, it worked.